# How can I replace stone_slab with bottom only double_stone_slab in Bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]I'm trying to replace `stone_slab` with `double_stone_slab` using the `/fill` command:

```
/fill -83,4,-369 -79,3,-375 double_stone_slab 0 replace stone_slab
```

However, every time I execute the command, it states:

> 0 blocks placed.

I've placed about 10 `stone_slab` in the target area.

---

How can I replace `stone_slab` with `double_stone_slab`?

<sub>***NOTE:** I want to replace the bottom slab. I do **NOT** want a slab on top.*</sub>

[image]

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se ^^ Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance.

Comment: Can you supply the values you're using for your fill coordinates (*start and end please*), along with the start and end coordinates of the slabs you're trying to place? It could be as simple as a misaligned `y` value, you never know.

Comment: x=-28  y= 5 z= -358
x= -48 y= 3 z =-374

Comment: What are the start and ending coordinates for the stone slabs you're trying to replace?

Comment: Can you give us the in-game names for the slabs on the left and the slabs on the right?

Comment: if you don't put the commas does it work?

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by saying that a double slab, by definition is the combination of a top and bottom slab of the same kind. So trying to replace a `stone_slab` with `double_stone_slab` will ***NOT*** result in a bottom only slab. With that, what it appears that you're trying to do is replace any top `stone_slab` with bottom `stone_slab`, which is easy to achieve.

---

I began by filling a `5x1x5` area with top only `stone_slab` using the `/fill` command: <sub>*{1}*</sub>

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~ ~5 stone_slab 8
```

[image: Screenshot of the results of the fill command execution.]

From here, I then used the the `/fill` command adding the `replace` argument to specify that I wanted to replace all top `stone_slab` with bottom `stone_slab`: <sub>*{2}*</sub>

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~ ~5 stone_slab 0 replace stone_slab 8
```

[image: Screenshot of the results of the fill command execution with the replace argument.]

<sub>***1.** Specifying a block state of `8` designates a top only `stone_slab`.*</sub>

<sub>***2.** Specifying a block state of `0` designates a bottom only `stone_slab`.*</sub>

---

<sub>***NOTE**: I moved around while tinkering with command output between screenshots, so the coordinates are different, but the point is the same.*</sub>

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I think I've put it wrong I've put up an image so you can see what I mean I don't want to move the slabs I just want to change the slabs from the ones on the left to the ones on the right